# How can I share a google staticmap with custom markers on facebook post with an image preview of the map?

Tags: facebook, google-maps-static-api

I create a staticmap link from a google map on my own site, and everything it's ok, the staticmap is created and look fine, but when I want to share the link (for example: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=11&scale=2&size=640x640&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue|label:1|13.497547316158656,-89.4810676574707&markers=color:blue|label:2|13.487198047231367,-89.3214225769043&sensor=false) on a facebook post, it doesn't generate the image preview of the map.

I need share it because it's part of a homework. I tried sharing a page with an img tag with the url of the staticmap, (this is the link of my example: http://demoshtml.chambadigital.com/prueba3.html), but when I share it on facebook, it doesn't show my markers, only it shows a map with a marker that actually it doesn't exist on my map. Could you help me, please?

Comment: Do you get any error? Have you tried to take a look into logs?

Comment: actually the problem is that when I want share the link on facebook, it doesn't generate the image preview that I need, I can post it.. but I need that facebook image preview...

Comment: Are you trying to do the same as guy in [this topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/52RDwMrzkSE)? If yes - then seems like you have to look for some workarounds because fb does not work quite well with what you need

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do. But you're right, I will need to look for other workarounds, thank you anyway. :(